# query not work in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT product_id,sum(quantity) AS total,price
FROM item,product
WHERE product.id=item.product_id
GROUP BY product_id
```

This query perfectly run in mysql but not work in oracle 11g XE.
it's says:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you either want

```
SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) AS total, sum(price) as total_price
FROM item, product
WHERE product.id = item.product_id
GROUP BY product_id;
```

or

```
SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) AS total, price
FROM item, product
WHERE product.id = item.product_id
GROUP BY product_id, price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have answered, Oracle requires you to explicitly `GROUP BY` any non-aggregated fields you SELECT.  And your DBA will be happiest if you use an ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT product_id, sum(quantity) AS total, price
  FROM item i
  JOIN product p ON (i.product_id = p.id)
 GROUP BY product_id, price;
```

Comment: Hi, Joshua. Why would a DBA be happy about the ANSI syntax of joins ?

Comment: @nop77svk 99% reduced chance of an accidental Cartesian join from missing relationship in the where clause. I've sent this link to dozens of developers at my shop: http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618 (I'm a DBA, as you probably guessed.)

Comment: There was one time I was asked to help a developer figure out why a query was taking so long. Turns out it was a huge 7 table join with legacy syntax. One of the joining conditions was missing from the where clause, so Cartesian join resulted. Difficult to spot unless you carefully trace all the where predicates.  Problem vanishes when using ANSI syntax.

Comment: So I thought it was about cartesians. And I'll add: The ANSI syntax allows for joins not possible with the "legacy" syntax, like left outer joining a table on 2+ columns from 2+ tables. Simply fails on 11gR2 when legacy-written. Thank you for your reply. You know, I just wondered why particularly a DBA would be happy about it, since a developer should be happy about it in the first place, cause it (the ANSI syntax) **always** improves readability of a query. :-) But, alas, most of the (pro) Oracle devs I met in my life are legacy-addicted analphabets, readability won't matter to them anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting how subjective the matter is to people. There are some die-hard old school devs that insist that legacy join syntax is easier to read.  I think the OraFAQ link above said it best: that ANSI syntax lets you keep the join critieria next to the tables where they belong, and the predicates under the WHERE clause truly behave as filters.  And if you want to do an ANSI `FULL JOIN` with legacy syntax, then you have to `UNION` together two queries with joins --> ugly code and not good unless you get paid per line of crap code.